# www page always returns 302

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, www

We are changing our company website, old wordpress website is on old server centos/apache with ip 10.10.10.20 and the new one has different ip 10.10.10.200. The deal was to just edit dns entries, as the new website should have the same domain. The old ip was removed from dns and the url was https://www.example.com.

The new website on https://example.com works perfectly, but the https://www.example.com or [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)  show error: This site can’t be reached

/etc/httpd/conf.d/site.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/example.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/DigiCertCA.crt
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        Redirect "/" "https://example.com/"
        ErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/error_log
        CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess file

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
    
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # BEGIN Redirects
    RewriteEngine On
    # 301 redirect www to non-www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    # 301 redirect to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    # END Redirects
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    
    # END WordPress
```

The developer installed the plugin for redirection and the dns has entries like: example.com 10.10.10.200 and alias [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

$curl -I [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 24 Feb 2022 19:21:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.37 (centos) OpenSSL/1.1.1k
Location: https://example.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I just want www pages to redirect to https://example.com , could it be that google/crawler remembered our old ip address and always tries old dns entry? Should I wait a few days ? It's been more than 48h. Can this be fixed somehow?

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest that you provide us with real DNS names so we can look them up and verify that things is correctly configured, and also test the problem ourself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I can post any results here, which test should I do?